# how to make saveAsTextFile NOT split output into multiple file?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When using Scala in Spark, whenever I dump the results out using `saveAsTextFile`, it seems to split the output into multiple parts. I'm just passing a parameter(path) to it.

```
val year = sc.textFile("apat63_99.txt").map(_.split(",")(1)).flatMap(_.split(",")).map((_,1)).reduceByKey((_+_)).map(_.swap)
year.saveAsTextFile("year")
```

1. Does the number of outputs correspond to the number of reducers it uses?
2. Does this mean the output is compressed?
3. I know I can combine the output together using bash, but is there an option to store the output in a single text file, without splitting?? I looked at the API docs, but it doesn't say much about this.

Comment: It's generally bad practice to only use one file in Big Data if that file is large.

Comment: What's the best practice then if the output was, say, a sorted file?  Keep it as a collection of files and make the many output file names be some sort of index (i.e. something like first file is named "aa", middle ones would be like "fg", last one "zzy")?

Comment: It's often the case that an heavy spark job only generates a very small output (aggregation, kpis, popularities, ...) which is produced on hdfs, but most likely to be latter used by applications unrelated to big data. Cleaner and easier in this case to have a well named single file for transfers and consumption.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

The reason it saves it as multiple files is because the computation is distributed. If the output is small enough such that you think you can fit it on one machine, then you can end your program with

```
val arr = year.collect()
```

And then save the resulting array as a file, Another way would be to use a custom partitioner, [`partitionBy`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions), and make it so everything goes to one partition though that isn't advisable because you won't get any parallelization.

If you require the file to be saved with `saveAsTextFile` you can use `coalesce(1,true).saveAsTextFile()`. This basically means do the computation then coalesce to 1 partition. You can also use `repartition(1)` which is just a wrapper for `coalesce` with the shuffle argument set to true. Looking through the source of [RDD.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L307) is how I figured most of this stuff out, you should take a look.

Comment: how do you save an array as text file?? there is no saveAsTextFile function for an array. just for RDD.

Comment: @user2773013 well the approach for that would be `coalesce` or the `partition` approach I suggested, but there is really no point in storing on hdfs if it's only on 1 node which is why using collect is really the correct way to go

Comment: Very useful answer.... Haven't seen partitionBy or coalesce in the tutorials Ive read...

Answer (score 44):

For those working with **a larger dataset**:

- `rdd.collect()` should not be used in this case as it will *collect* all data as an `Array` in the driver, which is the easiest way to get out of memory.
- `rdd.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile()` should also not be used as the parallelism of upstream stages will be lost to be performed on a single node, where data will be stored from.
- `rdd.coalesce(1, shuffle = true).saveAsTextFile()` **is the best simple option** as it will keep the processing of upstream tasks parallel and then only perform the shuffle to one node (`rdd.repartition(1).saveAsTextFile()` is an exact synonym).
- `rdd.saveAsSingleTextFile()` as provided bellow additionally allows one to store the rdd in a single file **with a specific name** while keeping the parallelism properties of `rdd.coalesce(1, shuffle = true).saveAsTextFile()`.

---

Something that can be inconvenient with `rdd.coalesce(1, shuffle = true).saveAsTextFile("path/to/file.txt")` is that it actually produces a file whose path is `path/to/file.txt/part-00000` and not `path/to/file.txt`.

The following solution `rdd.saveAsSingleTextFile("path/to/file.txt")` will actually produce a file whose path is `path/to/file.txt`:

```
package com.whatever.package

import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, FileUtil, Path}
import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodec

object SparkHelper {

  // This is an implicit class so that saveAsSingleTextFile can be attached to
  // SparkContext and be called like this: sc.saveAsSingleTextFile
  implicit class RDDExtensions(val rdd: RDD[String]) extends AnyVal {

    def saveAsSingleTextFile(path: String): Unit =
      saveAsSingleTextFileInternal(path, None)

    def saveAsSingleTextFile(path: String, codec: Class[_ <: CompressionCodec]): Unit =
      saveAsSingleTextFileInternal(path, Some(codec))

    private def saveAsSingleTextFileInternal(
        path: String, codec: Option[Class[_ <: CompressionCodec]]
    ): Unit = {

      // The interface with hdfs:
      val hdfs = FileSystem.get(rdd.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)

      // Classic saveAsTextFile in a temporary folder:
      hdfs.delete(new Path(s"$path.tmp"), true) // to make sure it's not there already
      codec match {
        case Some(codec) => rdd.saveAsTextFile(s"$path.tmp", codec)
        case None        => rdd.saveAsTextFile(s"$path.tmp")
      }

      // Merge the folder of resulting part-xxxxx into one file:
      hdfs.delete(new Path(path), true) // to make sure it's not there already
      FileUtil.copyMerge(
        hdfs, new Path(s"$path.tmp"),
        hdfs, new Path(path),
        true, rdd.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration, null
      )
      // Working with Hadoop 3?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50545815/9297144

      hdfs.delete(new Path(s"$path.tmp"), true)
    }
  }
}
```

which can be used this way:

```
import com.whatever.package.SparkHelper.RDDExtensions

rdd.saveAsSingleTextFile("path/to/file.txt")
```

```scala
// Or if the produced file is to be compressed:
import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec
rdd.saveAsSingleTextFile("path/to/file.txt.gz", classOf[GzipCodec])
```

This snippet:

- First stores the rdd with `rdd.saveAsTextFile("path/to/file.txt")` in a temporary folder `path/to/file.txt.tmp` as if we didn't want to store data in one file (which keeps the processing of upstream tasks parallel)
- And then only, using the [hadoop file system api](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs//r2.7.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html), we proceed with the [merge](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs//r2.7.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.html#copyMerge(org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20boolean,%20org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration,%20java.lang.String)) (`FileUtil.copyMerge()`) of the different output files to create our final output single file `path/to/file.txt`.

Comment: whats the issue with coalesce here? why choose repartition over coalesce?

Answer (score 23):

You could call `coalesce(1)` and then `saveAsTextFile()` - but it might be a bad idea if you have a lot of data. Separate files per split are generated just like in Hadoop in order to let separate mappers and reducers write to different files. Having a single output file is only a good idea if you have very little data, in which case you could do collect() as well, as @aaronman said.

Comment: Nice didn't think of `coalesce` cleaner than messing around with the partitioner, that being said I still think if your goal is to get it to one file `collect` is probably the right way to do it

Comment: this works. But, if you use coalesce, that means you are only using 1 reducer. Wouldn't this slow the process because only 1 reducer is used??

Comment: Yes, but that is what you are asking for.  Spark outputs one file per partition.  On the othe hand, why do you care about the number of files? When reading files in spark you can just specify the parent directory and all of the partitions are read as a single RDD

Comment: Do not `coalesce(1)` please, [unless you know what you are doing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38986776/nullpointerexception-in-spark-rdd-map-when-submitted-as-a-spark-job/38986964#38986964).

Answer (score 4):

As others have mentioned, you can collect or coalesce your data set to force Spark to produce a single file. But this also limits the number of Spark tasks that can work on your dataset in parallel. I prefer to let it create a hundred files in the output HDFS directory, then use `hadoop fs -getmerge /hdfs/dir /local/file.txt` to extract the results into a single file in the local filesystem. This makes the most sense when your output is a relatively small report, of course.

Answer (score 2):

In Spark 1.6.1 the format is as shown below. It creates a single output file.It is best practice to use it if the output is small enough to handle.Basically what it does is that it returns a new RDD that is reduced into numPartitions partitions.If you're doing a drastic coalesce, e.g. to numPartitions = 1, this may result in your computation taking place on fewer nodes than you like (e.g. one node in the case of numPartitions = 1)

```
pair_result.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("/app/data/")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call `repartition()` and follow this way:

```
val year = sc.textFile("apat63_99.txt").map(_.split(",")(1)).flatMap(_.split(",")).map((_,1)).reduceByKey((_+_)).map(_.swap)

var repartitioned = year.repartition(1)
repartitioned.saveAsTextFile("C:/Users/TheBhaskarDas/Desktop/wc_spark00")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to do it in the next version of Spark, in the current version 1.0.0 it's not possible unless you do it manually somehow, for example, like you mentioned, with a bash script call.

Comment: the next version of Spark is here and it's not obvious how to do it :(

Answer (score 1):

I also want to  mention that the documentation clearly states that users should be careful when calling coalesce with a real small number of  partitions  . this can cause upstream partitions to inherit this number of partitions.

I would not recommend  using coalesce(1) unless really required.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer to output a single file. I just added `coalesce(1)`

```
val year = sc.textFile("apat63_99.txt")
              .map(_.split(",")(1))
              .flatMap(_.split(","))
              .map((_,1))
              .reduceByKey((_+_)).map(_.swap)
year.saveAsTextFile("year")
```

Code:

```
year.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("year")
```