# saveAsTextFile method in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In my project, I have three input files and make the file names as args(0) to args(2), I also have a output filename as args(3), in the source code, I use

```
val sc = new SparkContext()
var log = sc.textFile(args(0))
for(i <- 1 until args.size - 1) log = log.union(sc.textFile(args(i)))
```

I do nothing to the log but save it as a text file by using

```
log.coalesce(1, true).saveAsTextFile(args(args.size - 1))
```

but it still save to 3 file as part-00000、part-00001、part-00002, So is there any way that I can save the three input files to an output file?

Comment: Is this your complete program? It looks okay, you should have something like one file `part-00000` and `_SUCCESS` in the output directory. Note that the argument to the `saveAsTextFile` is actually a directory name, where the output is saved.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! In fact i do some action to the log.  Just now, I try it and find that it is useful, maybe something error to my project, I will see it!

Comment: I just tried this myself and I end up with only a single output.  Are you running spark locally or in a cluster?

Answer (score 2):

Having multiple output files is a standard behavior of multi-machine clusters like Hadoop or Spark. The number of output files depends on the number of reducers.

How to "solve" it in Hadoop:
[merge output files after reduce phase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700068/merge-output-files-after-reduce-phase)

How to "solve" in Spark:
[how to make saveAsTextFile NOT split output into multiple file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371259/how-to-make-saveastextfile-not-split-output-into-multiple-file)

A good info you can get also here:
http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/How-to-make-Spark-merge-the-output-file-td322.html

So, you were right about `coalesce(1,true)`. However, it is very inefficient. Interesting is that (as @climbage mentioned in his remark) your code is working if you run it locally.

What you might try is to read the files first and then save the output.

```
...
val sc = new SparkContext()
var str = new String("")
for(i <- 0 until args.size - 1){
   val file = sc.textFile(args(i))       
   file.foreach(line => str+= line)
}
//and now you might save the content
str.coalesce(1, true).saveAsTextFile("out")
```

Note: this code is also extremely inefficient and working for small files only!!! You need to come up with a better code.  I wouldn't try to reduce number of file but process multiple outputs files instead.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned your problem is somewhat unavoidable via the standard API's as the assumption is that you are dealing with large quanatities of data. However, if I assume your data is manageable you could try the following

```
import java.nio.file.{Paths, Files}    
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

Files.write(Paths.get("./test_file"), data.collect.mkString("\n").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
```

What I am doing here is converting the RDD into a String by performing a collect and then mkString. I would suggest not doing this in production. It works fine for local data analysis (Working with 5gb~ of local data)