# Spark dataframe is not ordered after sort

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm processing a JSON file to generate two JSON files using Spark (version 1.6.1). The size of input file is about 30~40G (100M records). For the generated files, the bigger one is about 10G ~ 15G (30M records), the smaller one is about 500M ~ 750M (1.5M records). both result files are facing the below problems:

I invoked the "sort" method for the dataframe, after that performed "repartition" to merge the results into a single file. Then I checked the generated file, found **in an interval the records are ordered, but the whole file is not ordered globally**. e.g. the key (constructed from 3 columns) of the last record (line no 1.9M) in the file is "(ou7QDj48c, 014, 075)", but the key of a middle record in the file (line no 375K) is "(pzwzh5vm8, 003, 023)"

```
pzwzh5vm8 003 023
...
ou7QDj48c 014 075
```

When I tested code locally using a relatively small input source (input file 400K lines), such case doesn't happen at all.

My concrete code is shown below:

```scala
big_json = big_json.sort($"col1", $"col2", $"col3", $"col4")
big_json.repartition(1).write.mode("overwrite").json("filepath")
```

Could anyone give an advice? Thank you.

(I've also noticed that [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31736519/sparksql-dataframe-order-by-across-partitions) discussed a similar problem, but there is not a good solution till now. If this phenomenon is really resulted from repartition operation, could anyone help me to effectively transform dataframe to a single JSON file without transform it into RDD, while keep the sorted order? Thanks)

**Solution**:

Really appreciate for the help from @manos @eliasah and @pkrishna. I had thought about using coalesce after read your comments but after having investigated its performance I gave up the idea.

The final solution is: sort the dataframe and write into JSON, without any repartition or coalesce. After the whole work is done, call the HDFS command below

```bash
hdfs dfs -getmerge /hdfs/file/path/part* ./local.json
```

This command is far better than my imagine. It neither takes too much time nor too much space, and gives me a good single file. I just used `head` and `tail` on the huge result file and it seems totally ordered.

Comment: Don't repartition. Let it create multiple files and then read them one by one they should be in proper sorting order.

Comment: You might want to post __solution__ part as an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What's happening is that you are **repartitioning** **after** your **sort** action.

`repartition` reshuffles the data in the RDD randomly to create either more or fewer partitions and balance it across them. This always shuffles all data over the network.

Under the hood, it uses `coalesce` and `shuffle` to redistribute data. 
This is why your data isn't sorted anymore.

You can check the code for [reference](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/279bd4aa5fddbabdb0383a3f6f0fc8d91780e092/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L413).

Answer (score 4):

Since the partition count is set to 1 in your example, which means the partition is reduced to 1.

To decrease the number of partitions in the rdd, spark provides a transformation coalesce (with shuffle=false) which preserves the order.

As eliasah, mentioned that repartition under the hood using coalesce. It calls coalesce with shuffle=true. So the coalesce transformation can be used instead of repartition with shuffle=false.