# How to save RDD data into json files, not folders

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am receiving the streaming data `myDStream` (`DStream[String]`) that I want to save in S3 (basically, for this question, it doesn't matter where exactly do I want to save the outputs, but I am mentioning it just in case).

The following code works well, but it saves folders with the names like `jsonFile-19-45-46.json`, and then inside the folders it saves files `_SUCCESS` and `part-00000`.

Is it possible to save each `RDD[String]` (these are JSON strings) data into the JSON **files**, not the folders? I thought that `repartition(1)` had to make this trick, but it didn't.

```
    myDStream.foreachRDD { rdd => 
       // datetimeString = ....
       rdd.repartition(1).saveAsTextFile("s3n://mybucket/keys/jsonFile-"+datetimeString+".json")
    }
```

Comment: See [how to make saveAsTextFile NOT split output into multiple file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371259/how-to-make-saveastextfile-not-split-output-into-multiple-file) for why it works this way and what to do about it.

Comment: @hoyland: I checked this thread and the recommendation is to use `coalesce(1,true)`. I tried this solution, but I still get folders with `SUCCESS` and `part00000` instead of json files. In my case I know that the size of each RDD will be relatively small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is no option to save it as a file. Because it's a distributed processing framework and it's not a good practice write on single file rather than each partition writes it's own files in the specified path.

> We can pass only output directory where we wanted to save the data. OutputWriter will create file(s)(depends on partitions) inside specified path with `part-` file name prefix.

Comment: Yes, I understand. For my application I decided to use `rdd.collect.mkString("\n")` and then to upload the strings to S3 as files using Amazon SDK. It works for for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `rdd.collect.mkString("\n")` you can use hadoop Filesystem library to cleanup output by moving `part-00000` file into it's place. Below code works perfectly on local filesystem and HDFS, but I'm unable to test it with S3:

```
val outputPath = "path/to/some/file.json"
rdd.saveAsTextFile(outputPath + "-tmp")

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
val fs = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
fs.rename(new Path(outputPath + "-tmp/part-00000"), new Path(outputPath))
fs.delete(new Path(outputPath  + "-tmp"), true)
```

Answer (score 0):

For JAVA I implemented this one. Hope it helps:

```
    val fs = FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration());
    File dir = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/my.csv/");
    File[] files = dir.listFiles((d, name) -> name.endsWith(".csv"));
    fs.rename(new Path(files[0].toURI()), new Path(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/csvDirectory/newData.csv"));
    fs.delete(new Path(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/my.csv/"), true);
```