# Specifying the filename when saving a DataFrame as a CSV

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

Say I have a Spark DF that I want to save to disk a CSV file.  In Spark 2.0.0+, one can convert **`DataFrame(DataSet[Rows])`** as a **`DataFrameWriter`** and use the **`.csv`** method to write the file.

The function is defined as

```
def csv(path: String): Unit
    path : the location/folder name and not the file name.
```

Spark stores the csv file at the location specified by creating CSV files with name - part-*.csv.

Is there a way to save the CSV with specified filename instead of part-*.csv ? Or possible to specify prefix to instead of part-r ?

**Code :**

```
df.coalesce(1).write.csv("sample_path")
```

**Current Output :**

```
sample_path
|
+-- part-r-00000.csv
```

**Desired Output :**

```
sample_path
|
+-- my_file.csv
```

**Note :** The coalesce function is used to output a single file and the executor has enough memory to collect the DF without memory error.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot answer here, so for java users:
        
        val fs = FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration());
        File dir = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/my.csv/");
        File[] files = dir.listFiles((d, name) -> name.endsWith(".csv"));
        fs.rename(new Path(files[0].toURI()), new Path(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/csvDirectory/newData.csv"));
        fs.delete(new Path(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/my.csv/"), true);

Comment: I get around this issue in pyspark by calling toPandas() and then just saving via a pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It's not possible to do it directly in Spark's `save`

Spark uses Hadoop File Format, which requires data to be partitioned - that's why you have `part-` files. You can easily change filename after processing just like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40792434/spark-dataframe-save-in-single-file-on-hdfs-location?rq=1) question

In Scala it will look like:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._
val fs = FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
val file = fs.globStatus(new Path("path/file.csv/part*"))(0).getPath().getName()

fs.rename(new Path("csvDirectory/" + file), new Path("mydata.csv"))
fs.delete(new Path("mydata.csv-temp"), true)
```

or just:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._
val fs = FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
fs.rename(new Path("csvDirectory/data.csv/part-0000"), new Path("csvDirectory/newData.csv"))
```

Edit: As mentioned in comments, you can also write your own OutputFormat, please see documents for [information](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/FAQ#How_do_I_change_final_output_file_name_with_the_desired_name_rather_than_in_partitions_like_part-00000.2C_part-00001.3F) about this approach to set file name

Comment: @eliasah Didn't know it. But stil it's not out of the box in Spark

Comment: However good point, I will edit my answer later to show this possibility :)

Comment: it's always good to remind spark users that there is an underlying hadoop/hdfs layer

Comment: I think you have two typos. (1) getting field values from scala arrays is in (brackets) not [square brackets]. So it should be fs.globStatus(new Path("path/file.csv/part*"))(0). (2) I think the sc.hadoopConfiguration does not take parameters so you should omit the () that you have at the end. My scala REPL throws this very clear error: error: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration does not take parameters. But thanks for the answer! Super Helpful!

Comment: @Max Thank you :) This code was ported from Java version, I've edited my answer :)

Comment: Thanks! consider these changes     val file = fs.globStatus(new Path(s"$sinkDir/part*"))(0).getPath()

    fs.rename(file, new Path(s"$sinkDir/gremlin.fastq"))

Comment: sc.hadoopConfiguration does not take parameters in the second example as well, so parentheses () should be omitted there too :)

Comment: I'm new to spark + Hadoop.. what implication to resources and performance would this approach have? Will it all be executed on the spark Driver?

Comment: If I have multiple files in a folder, will `fs.globStatus(new Path("path/file.csv/part*"))(0).getPath().getName()` give me the latest one?