# How to store JSON dataframe with comma sepearted

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I need to write record of dataframe to a json file. If I write the dataframe into the file it stores like `{"a":1} {"b":2}`, I want to write the dataframe like this `[{"a":1} ,{"b":2}]`. Can you please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you help with sample data output as a column? It is not very clear with your explanation.

Comment: Yeah, If I write the dataframe into the file it prints like `{"a":1} {"b":2}`, I want to write the dataframe like this `[{"a":1} ,{"b":2}]`

Comment: can you show your dataframe schem & also show code how you are writing to file ?

Comment: suresh,  I am not understanding the purpose of it. can be achived thorugh program gimmicks like lit(1) , but its fatal and substandard. @Shu what is your opinion on this ? I feel it will overkill the performance using `collect` functions for big/moderate datasets.

Comment: I am processing JSON and storing into a file as above format. @Ram Ghadiyaram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`to_json`** function to create `array of json objects` then use **`.saveAsTextFile`** to save the json object.

**`Example:`**

```
#sample dataframe
df=spark.createDataFrame([("a",1),("b",2)],["id","name"])

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.groupBy(lit("1")).\
agg(collect_list(struct(*[df.columns])).alias("cl")).\
select(to_json("cl").alias("jsn")).\
rdd.\
map(lambda x:x["jsn"]).\
saveAsTextFile("<path>")

cat <path>
#[{"id":"a","name":1},{"id":"b","name":2}]
```

Comment: You are at next level............................. @Shu, my problem solved....! Thanks a lot................