# Spark: Generate txt files

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have data stored in parqueue format, i want to generate the delimitered text file from spark with row limit of 100 rows per file. is this possible to handle it from spark notebooks ? 
I am building ADF pipeline which triggers this notebook and the assume output is of textfile something like the below format please suggest me the possible ways .

5431732167  899 1011381 1   teststring
5431732163  899         912 teststring
5431932119  899 108808  40  teststring
5432032116  899 1082223 40  teststring

i also have a need to process the batch of text file and load them into database, please suggest the options to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Manoj.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get 1000 records from dataframe and write into a file using PySpark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61412292/how-to-get-1000-records-from-dataframe-and-write-into-a-file-using-pyspark)

Answer (score 0):

This question appears to be a functional duplicate of: [How to get 1000 records from dataframe and write into a file using PySpark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61412292/how-to-get-1000-records-from-dataframe-and-write-into-a-file-using-pyspark/61412863#61412863)

Before running your job to write your CSV files, set `maxRecordsPerFile`, so in Spark SQL:

```
set spark.sql.files.maxRecordsPerFile = 100
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use maxRecordsPerFile with the CSV output. This will not guarantee that you will have only one file with less than 100 records though, only that there will be no files with more than 100 rows. Spark writes in parallel so this cannot be ensured across nodes.

```scala
df
  .write
  .option("maxRecordsPerFile", 100)
  .csv(outputPath)
```

If your data is very small, you can coalesce it to 1 partition and ensure that only 1 file is bigger than 100 rows, but then you loose the parallel processing speed advantage (most of your cluster will be unused during the last calculation and the write)

For writing to databases, the solution depends on the particular database. One example many databases support is JDBC, spark can read/write data with it, see: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html