# Dataframe output to one csv file with my name (Spark, Scala)

Tags: scala, dataframe, csv, apache-spark

Please tell me how to save the dataframe to a file with MY NAME in csv format. It may not work directly, but what workaround is there for this? We are talking about large volumes.
So far, I can save it in a folder with my name, and the names part-0000..., but I would like to put it in a file with my name and maybe something more productive than repartition()

Comment: Hope this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41990086/specifying-the-filename-when-saving-a-dataframe-as-a-csv

Comment: You can coallesce to 1, then RDD[String] and foreachPartition. Use  the Iterator[String] and use any IO api to create you file. note that you should include the header first.

Comment: Thanks so much. - dsk!!!