# How not to write duplicate data(parquet) to hdfs using java spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, parquet

I am new to java, spark and hdfs
Here is my use case:
I read a log file, select the events that I am interested in and using java spark persist it as parquet in hdfs.
Now if the same log is re-sent, select the events that I am interested in, then how do I ensure that I do not re-write this duplicate data back in the hdfs? What if only a some log messages are duplicate and others are new? As in log file is sent in every 10 hours wether it has rolled over or not, then there will be some new data with pre-existing data.

Comment: You'd need to read existing files, then do some compare the existing data to what you're about to write. Maybe use SparkSQL joins. HDFS doesn't compare files on its own

Answer (score 1):

Before saving your dataframe to hdfs, you need to perform comparaison with all existing files in order to check duplication.

What I'll do, if I was to implement this, is the following steps:

After saving a dataframe of logs into hdfs, i'll rename it directly (It's not possible to choose a name for a hdfs file because spark uses hadoop File Format, which requires data to be partitioned). The file name will be something containing an id which is a checksum of the content for exemple

file_logs_120EA8A25E5D487BF68B5F7096440019.parquet

For checksum calcul, you will find a lot of available libraries.

Before saving my log dataframe, i'll get all checksums from the files in the destination directory and check if my current checksum exists in that list. If it does not exists then i'll save it and of course rename it (like mentioned before).

Pseudo-code in scala:

```
def saveLogFileToHdfs(source): Unit = {
//create the dataframe from source
val df = createDFLogsFromSource(source)
//get the checksum of my dataframe content. It'll be used for comparaison later
val dfSourceChecksum = getChecksum(df)
//save the dataframe into hdfs
if(checkDuplication(dfSourceChecksum, destinationPath))
saveAndRenameDF(df, dfSourceChecksum)
} 


def checkDuplication(checksum: String, path: Path): boolean = {
//we'll get a list of checksums from the path
val checksumList : List[String] = getListOfChecksums(path)
checksumList.contains(checksum)
}

def getListOfChecksums(path: Path) : List[String] = {
//loop over the directoty, use split in order to get the cheksum and yield to a list the results
}

def saveAndRenameDF(df: DataFrame, dfSourceChecksum: String): Unit = {
//perform the save and rename
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._
val fs = FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
fs.rename(new Path("path"), new Path("path_checksum.parquet"))
}
```

It also possible to use another approach, which is reading all files from the destination directory, create dataframes and compare your dataframe with all of them.

For that you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41990086/specifying-the-filename-when-saving-a-dataframe-as-a-csv)

```
if (firstDataFrame.exceptAll(secondDataFrame).head(1).isEmpty) {
//The two DF are equals, process here
} else {
//There is difference
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @shalnarkftw! I will try this.