# write to Google Cloud Storage using spark to absolute path

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to write a spark dataframe into google cloud storage. This dataframe has got some updates so I need a partition strategy. SO I need to write it into exact file in GCS.

i have Created a spark session as follows

```
        .config("fs.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem")\
        .config("fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS")\
        .config("fs.gs.project.id", project_id)\
        .config("fs.gs.auth.service.account.enable", "true")\
        .config("fs.gs.auth.service.account.project.id",project_id)\
        .config("fs.gs.auth.service.account.private.key.id",private_key_id)\
        .config("fs.gs.auth.service.account.private.key",private_key)\
        .config("fs.gs.auth.service.account.client.email",client_email)\
        .config("fs.gs.auth.service.account.email",client_email)\
        .config("fs.gs.auth.service.account.client.id",client_id)\
        .config("fs.gs.auth.service.account.auth.uri",auth_uri)\
        .config("fs.gs.auth.service.account.token.uri",token_uri)\
        .config("fs.gs.auth.service.account.auth.provider.x509.cert.url",auth_provider_x509_cert_url)\
        .config("fs.gs.auth.service.account.client_x509_cert_url",client_x509_cert_url)\
        .config("spark.sql.avro.compression.codec", "deflate")\
        .config("spark.sql.avro.deflate.level", "5")\
        .getOrCreate())
```

and I am writing into GCS using

```
df.write.format(file_format).save('gs://'+bucket_name+path+'/'+table_name+'/file_name.avro')
```

now i see a file written in GCP is in path

**gs://bucket_name/table_name/file_name.avro/--auto assigned name--.avro**

what i am expecting is the file to be written like in hadoop and final result of data file to be

**gs://bucket_name/table_name/file_name.avro**

can any one help me achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like limitation of standard Spark library. [Maybe this answer will help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40792434/spark-dataframe-save-in-single-file-on-hdfs-location).

You can also want to check alternative way of interacting with Google Cloud Storage from Spark, using [Cloud Storage Connector with Apache Spark](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/gcs-connector-spark-tutorial).