# How to save csv or xlsx into S3 bucket?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Even though actual use case is to store the data within shiny session,
I have simplified to be clear on the goal.

Could you please help me understand what changes I need to make in order to save the Csv/xlsx into S3 bucket ?

**Relevant but python**
[save a csv file into s3 bucket from pypark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56757688/save-a-csv-file-into-s3-bucket-from-pypark-dataframe)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(aws.s3)

# Authetication
aws.signature::use_credentials()
s3_bucket_link = # My s3 bucket link

  df = fread("mtcars.csv")

  #put object to s3
  aws.s3::put_object(object = "mtcars.csv",
                     file = "mtcars.csv",
                     bucket = s3_bucket_link)
  # Gives 403 or 404 error 
  # But when I check my S3 bucket file isnt available !!!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(aws.s3)

# Authetication
aws.signature::use_credentials()
s3_bucket_link = # s3 bucket link
complete_path = # Complete S3 bucket path including folder within S3 bucket link

write.csv(mtcars,"mtcars.csv")

aws.s3::s3write_using(mtcars,
                      object = paste0(complete_path,"mtcars.csv"),
                      FUN = write.csv,
                      bucket = s3_bucket_link)
```