# Spark dataframe(in Azure Databricks) save in single file on data lake(gen2) and rename the file

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am trying to achieve the same functionality as  this SO post [Spark dataframe save in single file on hdfs location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40792434/spark-dataframe-save-in-single-file-on-hdfs-location?rq=1) except my file is located in Azure Data Lake Gen2, and I am using pyspark in Databricks notebook.

Below is the code snippet I am using to rename the file

```
from py4j.java_gateway import java_import
java_import(spark._jvm, 'org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path')

destpath = "abfss://" + contianer + "@" + storageacct + ".dfs.core.windows.net/"
fs = spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())
file = fs.globStatus(sc._jvm.Path(destpath+'part*'))[0].getPath().getName()
#Rename the file
```

I receive an `IndexError: list index out of range` on this line

```
file = fs.globStatus(sc._jvm.Path(destpath+'part*'))[0].getPath().getName()
```

The part* file does exist in the folder.

1) Is this the right approach to rename file that databricks(pyspark) writes to Azure DataLakeGen2, if not,  how else can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by installing the [azure.storage.filedatalake](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-storage-file-datalake/12.0.0b5/index.html) client library in my databricks notebook. By using the FileSystemClient class and DataLakeFileClient class, I was able to rename the file in data lake gen2.