# Saving dataframe to json file with a specific name without creating partition files in Pyspark

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, partitioning, coalesce

I have a dataframe which I want to write it as single json file with a specific name. But it is creating a partitioned file within the stated filename. How do I get this to write data directly to the filename I passed into my parameter? Below is the code in Python:

```
df_3.coalesce(1).write.format('json').mode('overwrite').save(filename)
```

Data is now written to mylocation.json/part-00000 and I just want this to be mylocation.json file.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41990086/specifying-the-filename-when-saving-a-dataframe-as-a-csv

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40792434/spark-dataframe-save-in-single-file-on-hdfs-location

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to use `mode('append')` instead – and no need to use coalesce, unless you want to force it to run only on a single partition:

```
df_3.write.format('json').mode('append').save(filename)
```