# How do I write a pyspark dataframe into a CSV and read it into Pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pyspark

All methods that are mentioned in doing this seem to provide a folder, not a single .csv file that can be read to pandas dataframe.

Comment: Does your spark dataframe is large?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your PySpark dataframe is not that large, you can simply convert it to Pandas dataframe then save it to the disk:

```
# type(df) -> pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
df.toPandas.to_csv('out.csv')
```

However if it was large, you couldn't load it into a Pandas dataframe.

You can also use `write.csv` to write your data in multiple file and use a loop to read all chunks with Pandas:

```
import pathlib

df.write.option('header', True).csv('bigdata')

data = []
for csvfile in pathlib.Path('bigdata').glob('*.csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv(csvfile)
    data.append(df)
dfPD = pd.concat(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the following options:

1. If the file fit on a single node and you have enough free disk space on the node  you can use following line.

   df.toPandas().to_csv("fileName.csv", header=True)
2. You can try hdfs merge to merge all partitions onto a single file as follows. You can use subprocess to call command below in pyspark.

   hdfs dfs -getmerge /path_to_hdfs/*.*  /local_path/fileName.csv
3. If file must be on hdfs then you can use the answer on [Spark dataframe save in single file on hdfs location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40792434/spark-dataframe-save-in-single-file-on-hdfs-location)

Hope these helps.