# How to write a scala dataset in a json file

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I search a simple way of writing a scala dataset into a json file. I tried several ways like:

```
mydataset.write.json("selected_games.json")
```

or

```
mydataset.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").json("selected_games.json")
```

but it always creates a directory named "selected_games.json" with four files inside:

```
._SUCCESS.crc
.part-00000-59e33267-59a4-43dd-b7b0-6e3805b72160-c000.json.crc
_SUCCESS
part-00000-59e33267-59a4-43dd-b7b0-6e3805b72160-c000.json
```

how to have a single simple json file instead of this mess ?

Comment: Refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41990086/specifying-the-filename-when-saving-a-dataframe-as-a-csv and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40792434/spark-dataframe-save-in-single-file-on-hdfs-location