# Spark streaming JavaPairDStream to text file

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming, rdd, dstream

I am quite new on Spark streaming, and I am stuck saving my output.

My question is, how can I save the output of my JavaPairDStream in a text file, which is updated for each file only with the elements inside the DStream?

For example, with the wordCount example,

```
JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> wordCounts = words.mapToPair(
      new PairFunction<String, String, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String s) {
          return new Tuple2<>(s, 1);
        }
      }).reduceByKey(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer call(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
          return i1 + i2;
        }
      });
```

I would get the following output using `wordCounts.print()`,

```
(Hello,1)
(World,1)
```

I would like to write the last lines into a text file, which is refreshed each batch with the contents of `wordCounts`.

I've tried the following approach,

```
mappedRDD.dstream().saveAsTextFiles("output","txt");
```

This is generating a bunch of directories with several senseless files each batch time.

Another approach would be,

```
mappedRDD.foreachRDD(new Function2<JavaPairDStream<String, Integer>, Time, Void>() {
            public Void Call(JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> rdd, Time time)
            {
                //Something over rdd to save its content on a file???

                return null;
            }
        });
```

I would appreciate some help.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like below. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371259/how-to-make-saveastextfile-not-split-output-into-multiple-file) is SO post related to saveAsTextFile outputs multiple files.

```
 wordCounts.foreachRDD(rdd ->{
          if(!rdd.isEmpty()){
             rdd.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("c:\\temp\\count\\");
          }
      });
```