# Running pyspark word count example

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am just starting to learn Spark so please bear with me if this is too obvious.
I installed spark and I am able to run it in a terminal (by "./bin/pyspark").
But I fail to try the following example (word count):

```
path = os.path.join("sample-text.txt")
with open(path, "w") as testFile:
    _ = testFile.write("Hello world Hello")

file = sc.textFile(path)
counts = file.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")) \
             .map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
             .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)  

path2 = os.path.join("word-count.txt")
counts.saveAsTextFile(path2)
```

Everything went through, but when I was trying to open the output word-count.txt file, it says that this document cannot be opened.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> I was trying to open the output word-count.txt file

It creates a directory named `word-count.txt`, not a file.

```
$ ls word-count.txt
_SUCCESS   part-00000 part-00001 part-00002
$ cat word-count.txt/part-00000
(u'world', 1)
$ cat word-count.txt/part-00001
(u'Hello', 1)
(u'hello', 1)
```

Your code works. You have other permission problems with your OS that are preventing you from creating / opening the directory.

Related (scala, but same idea) - [how to make saveAsTextFile NOT split output into multiple file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371259/how-to-make-saveastextfile-not-split-output-into-multiple-file#24372343)

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful.