# How to add comma between JSON elements using Spark Scala

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, to-json

I'm loading a table data into a dataframe and creating multiple JSON part files. The structure of the data is good, but the elements in JSON are not separated by commas.

This is the output:

```
{"time_stamp":"2016-12-08 01:45:00","Temperature":0.8,"Energy":111111.5,"Net_Energy":1111.3}
{"time_stamp":"2016-12-08 02:00:00","Temperature":21.9,"Energy":222222.5,"Net_Energy":222.0}
```

I'm supposed to get something like this:

```
{"time_stamp":"2016-12-08 01:45:00","Temperature":0.8,"Energy":111111.5,"Net_Energy":1111.3},
{"time_stamp":"2016-12-08 02:00:00","Temperature":21.9,"Energy":222222.5,"Net_Energy":222.0}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: It's actually correct because it's a multi line file, not an array. If you look at the JSON standard it requieres no comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output is correct JSONlines output: one JSON record per line, separated by newlines. You do not need commas between the lines. In fact, that would be invalid JSON.

If you absolutely need to turn *the entire* output of a Spark job into a single JSON array of objects, there are two ways to do this:

1. For data that fits in driver RAM, `df.as[String].collect.mkString("[", ",", "]")`.
2. For data that does not fit in driver RAM... you really shouldn't do it... but if you absolutely have to, use shell operations to begin with `[`, add a comma to every line of output and end in `]`.

Comment: Third possibility, if data fits in an executor memory you can reduce number of partitions to 1 then apply a foreachPartition on it

Comment: @baitmbarek `foreachPartition` doesn't return a result so this leaves the problem if figuring out how to get the data out. Perhaps you were thinking of `mapPartitions` to return a single string and then write a massive single row text file using the ideas in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48712134/622495 (to control the file name).