# How can I add comma in JSON file produced by spark using python

Tags: python, apache-spark, databricks

I using python in databricks to produce a json file :

```
%python
data= spark.sql("select * from table")
data.repartition(1).write.mode("overwrite").json("data/")
```

what I'm getting is :

> {'id':1}
> {'id':2}
> {'id':}

but What I'm looking for is :

> {'id':1},
> {'id':2},
> {'id':}

how can I add the comma with python using databricks please ?

Comment: i think you can find an answer here already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58920400/how-to-add-comma-between-json-elements-using-spark-scala

Comment: this answer is for scala and not Python